# OmniAuth with Devise is rejected by FB after having worked perfectly for last couple months

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

Using OmniAuth with Devise, FB connect stopped working.  We're getting this at authentication: `http://localhost:3000/auth/failure?message=invalid_response`

Google has no suggestions on what causes this error or how to fix it and the OmniAuth docs don't either. I've tried digging through their code as well but the only mention of this error I've found is this, in /oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:

```
rescue ::MultiJson::DecodeError => e
  fail!(:invalid_response, e)
end
```

Any thoughts on how to solve?

Comment: have you tried re-syncing the time on your server? our server got off a few minutes and gave us a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

How it is said in this link, [OmniAuth Invalid Response Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528107/omniauth-invalid-response-error), what you can do is to upgrade to 1.9.2
We don't know why but now it works... Really weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance did you add the heroku_backup_task gem? That was the culprit for us, it seems to conflict with the json decoding going on in the OmniAuth gem.