# Omniauth with FourSquare issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, foursquare

**UPDATE 2011/05/01:**
I later carefully read through FourSquare's API document, and found it says:

> (Note that the request parameters are not JSON, they are standard HTTP keys and values.) All authentication is via OAuth2, which means that all requests MUST be https.

**Could this be the problem that I don't have a SSL connection in my development machine?**

---

Hi all! I am trying to connect FourSquare via Omniauth, I followed the Railscast toturial below, and change the provider into foursquare. But the return is always "invalid_credentials". I googled around and find that there's a discussion about this on GitHub(links below), but seems no conclusion yet. 
Anyone has idea what went wrong?

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :twitter, "XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX"
provider :foursquare, 'XXXXXXX',
'XXXXXXX'
end
```

[RailsCast Link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)

[Discussion on GitHub](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3af_xru01NGG4J%3ahttps://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/228?authenticity_token=cd14c95db8980ca62a1641eff4131a93e5a5d3d6%20%22message=invalid_credentials%22%20foursquare%20omniauth&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=tw&source=www.google.com.tw)

Comment: make sure you get new keys/secrets. The ones you posted pre-edit can still be viewed if someone looks at the edited content of this post.

Answer (score 1):

try to modify your provider initializer to point to your system's certificate path ("/etc/ssl/certs" on Ubuntu)

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :twitter, "XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX"
    provider :foursquare, 'XXXXXXX', {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}}}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a gem which will work with omniauth for foursquare.

https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-foursquare

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks fine, although you probably don't want to share your token/secret keys publicly.

Does the callback url that you used when registering your [foursquare oauth consumer](https://foursquare.com/oauth/) match the URL that you're testing with?  If you used http://www.foo.com/auth/foursquare/callback when registering your consumer, but are testing on your dev environment (http://localhost:3000/..), you'll see that auth/failure error.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I am testing this using DynDNS. The callback url i register is DynDNS. Would this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did: [OmniAuth Invalid Response Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528107/omniauth-invalid-response-error/5853814#5853814)