# What is essential knowhow for SSL in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am learning how to write Ruby on Rails (I have no programming background).

I am currently trying to use oauth to connect FourSquare, but I realized that I need an SSL connection to make things work ([see this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771103/omniauth-with-foursquare-issue)). I need some basic knowledge to get things done.

The problem: I find my knowledge for SSL in Rails is weak, can anyone give my some links to useful study materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a gem for the foursquare api? I think this seems to be the best solution. `https://github.com/ronaldwan/foursquare-api`.

Btw, creating a https connection is just defining your url connections staring with `https`.
I encourage you to check out how it is done in the `foursquare-api` gem. You can find it here: https://github.com/ronaldwan/foursquare-api/blob/master/lib/foursquare_node.rb

Also this file contains a method called `def self.exchange_access_token` which solves your problem I guess.

Comment: Thanks dombesz! I will definitely try this!